# AS3: Finding coordinates of a string array

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm learning AS3 and I'm programming a typewriter effect with a blinking cursor. Now I'm "cheating" moving the blinking cursor. Is there a way to locate coordinates of the string when they are shown on the screen?

```
var myString:String = "Lore Ipsum";
var myArray:Array = myString.split("");

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, myKeyDown);

function myKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
    tf.appendText(myArray.shift());
    BlinkingCursor.x = BlinkingCursor.x + 5;
}
```

Comment: Not for web. It's local animation.

Answer (score 0):

if you haven't already, check the api for the TextField object (assuming you're using a textfield and 'tf' stands for it): http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html

There should be some methods and properties that can help. At a quick glance TextField. getLineLength() may help as it seems to return the number of characters in a line (which you can multiply by char width if using a monospaced font).

If you're using a single line of text, you can probably just use the TextField.textWidth property.

Comment: Yes. I need to learn more. For now I've done a messy code that works.

Answer (score 0):

Untested but you can try :

```
function myKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
    tf.appendText(myArray.shift());
    BlinkingCursor.x = (tf.x + tf.width) + 5;
}
```

and regarding...

> Is there a way to locate coordinates of the string when they are shown
>   on the screen?

You should already know since you put the textField on screen in first place. Just to confirm :

- Did you use `tf.x =` & `tf.y =` to set coords before `addChild(tf)`?
- Does `trace("TF current X-pos : " + tf.x);` do like what you want?

Comment: It doesn't work. It returns coordinates of the tf that is always 0. The textfiled (tf) is placed at 0,0 and I want to know coordinates of the text inside that texfield. Thanks.